# Socket.io messages is not appending

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have app.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

and conversation.js

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('message', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append(msg);
});  

$(function(){
  $('#sendMessageForm').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('message', $('#text').val());
    $('#text').val('');

    return false;
  });
});
```

So, my server is receiving all messages that I sended and showing them in console log. But socket.on is not appending this messages. I thought that something wrong with socket, but this code is working

```
socket.on('messages', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append('some text');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server, you need to emit back, either to the same socket or every socket

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('message', msg); //to all sockets
  });
});
```

Also I guess your event name is `message` and not `messages`.

```
socket.on('message', function(msg){
           ^^^^^^^
  $('#messages').append('some text');
});
```